# can java applets take over your computer?

Tags: java-applet

can it execute programs on my computer ?

Comment: How to stopped applet from interruting my games . The applet shut down my game. I want it to stopped messing up my games.

Answer (score 4):

Only if either:

- You explicitly grant the applet increased rights (this also requires the applet to be [cryptographically signed](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/signedapplets.html), which in theory allows you to find out who wrote it and sue them when it turns out to be damaging)
- Your JVM or Java browser plugin has a security hole that the applet exploits - unfortunately in recent years there has been a constant stream of such security holes being found.

Comment: (You can cryptographically sign your jars with a completely made up certificate. The users will see a differently coloured dialog.)

Answer (score 2):

No. Java has a built in security mechanism will prevents applets from performing certain method calls. See the documentation for Runtime#exec(), for example.